# Compare, update or copy data from outside report

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compare a main planning file (let's call it Main.xlsm) and data that is provided by our ERP system (ERP.xlsm).

I'm looking to:

1) open a window to select the source file (ERP system dump).

2) compare unique ID values from column F in both files (Sheet RAPORT in Main.xlsm and Sheet1 in ERP.xlsm) and:

- If there is a match between Main.xlsm and ERP.xlsm - update values in Main with values from ERP (all data - rows A:AK)
- if there is an entry in ERP but no entry in Main - add the whole row with that ID (A:AK)
- if there is an entry in Main but no data in ERP - place value "0" in row "R" in the Main file

Bonus round: Every time one of the above happens, place a time/date stamp in column "AL" in the row from the unique ID it altered.

I tried the code below (original version, not altered by me). I can't figure out how to achieve all from above.

```vb
Sub import_tickets()
    'run this when the active file is the main ticket list and the active sheet is the ticket list
    'exported file must be open already, and the ticket list must be the active sheet
    Dim exported_file As String
    exported_file = "exported file.xlsx"
    header_exists = True 'if exported file doesn't have a header, set this to false!
    starting_row = 1
    If header_exists Then starting_row = 2

    Dim first_blank_row As Long
    first_blank_row = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Offset(1, 0).Row

    Dim r As Long
    r = starting_row
    Dim found As Range
    cur_ticket_num = Workbooks(exported_file).ActiveSheet.Range("a" & r).Value
    Do While Not cur_ticket_num = ""
        'look for current ticket number in main file
        Set found = Columns("a:a").Find(what:=cur_ticket_num, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If found Is Nothing Then
            'add info to end of main file
            write_line_from_export exported_file, r, first_blank_row
            first_blank_row = first_blank_row + 1
        Else
            'overwrite existing line of main file
            write_line_from_export exported_file, r, found.Row
        End If
        r = r + 1
        cur_ticket_num = Workbooks(exported_file).ActiveSheet.Range("a" & r).Value
    Loop
End Sub

Sub write_line_from_export(src_filename As String, src_r As Long, dest_r As Long)
    For c = 1 To 24
        Cells(dest_r, c).Value = Workbooks(src_filename).ActiveSheet.Cells(src_r, c).Value
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that uses a Dictionary object to compare the ID column between the 2 sheets.

```
Sub import_tickets()

  Dim sERPFileName As String
  Dim wbERP As Workbook, wsERP As Worksheet
  Dim wbMain As Workbook, wsMain As Worksheet
  Dim r, startrow, lastrow As Long
  Dim ID
  Dim dictERP
  Set dictERP = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
    sERPFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
  End With

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  ' process ERP workbook
  Set wbERP = Workbooks.Open(sERPFileName, , xlReadOnly)
  Set wsERP = wbERP.Sheets("Sheet1")
  startrow = 2 ' assume has header
  lastrow = wsERP.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

  For r = startrow To lastrow
   ID = wsERP.Range("F" & r).Value
   If dictERP.exists(ID) Then
     MsgBox "Duplicate ID (" & ID & ") found in " & sERPFileName
   Else
     dictERP.Add ID, r
   End If
  Next r

  ' process MAIN workbook
  Set wbMain = ThisWorkbook
  Set wsMain = wbMain.Sheets("RAPORT")
  startrow = 2 ' assume has header
  lastrow = wsMain.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

  For r = startrow To lastrow
   ID = wsMain.Range("F" & r).Value
   If dictERP.exists(ID) Then
     ' update
     wsERP.Rows(dictERP(ID)).Columns("A:AK").Copy wsMain.Range("A" & r)
     wsMain.Range("L" & r) = "Updated " & Now
     dictERP.Remove (ID)
   Else
     ' set col R = 0
     wsMain.Range("R" & r).Value = 0
     wsMain.Range("L" & r) = "No Change " & Now
   End If
  Next r

  ' add from ERP those not matched
  If dictERP.Count > 0 Then
    For Each ID In dictERP.keys
      r = dictERP(ID)
      lastrow = lastrow + 1
      wsERP.Rows(r).Columns("A:AK").Copy wsMain.Range("A" & lastrow)
      wsMain.Range("L" & lastrow) = "Added " & Now
    Next
  End If

  wbERP.Close
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  If dictERP.Count Then
    MsgBox dictERP.Count & " rows added"
  Else
    MsgBox "Done"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing! It works perfect! Thank you very, very much :)